# Hide/Show a div on button click jquery FOUNDATION

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

Here is my Code:

```
$('#btnmap').toggle(function(){
    $('#btnmap').val('Show Map');
    $('#map_canvas').hide();
}, function() {
    $('#btnmap').val('Hide Map');
    $('#map_canvas').show();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="flex-video"></div>
<input type="button" class="secondary small radius button right" name="btnmap" id="btnmap" value="Hide Map" />
```

When my page loads it adds display:none to my button instead. 
Please help me.

Comment: Could you please recreate the issue in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnmap').click(function(e) {
        $('#map_canvas').toggle('fast');
        if($('#btnmap').val()=='Hide Map'){
            $('#btnmap').val('Show map');
        }
        else{
            $('#btnmap').val('Hide Map');
            }
    });
});
</script>
```